# Using bash to navigate to a file in Finder

Tags: macos, bash, navigation

I drag a lot of graphic files from Finder directly into InDesign and Photoshop. I use a vey simple bash script to quickly open the directory containing the file.

```
cd "/Volumes/Server/Resources/stock1/"

open .
```

The script opens the correct directory, but I would like to know how to get it to also go to a specified file (e.g., image.eps) and highlight/select it.
 The directories I work with contain hundreds of files and have hard-to-look-through names. This would be a huge time-saver.

Thanks so much for any help. I'm using Mac OSX 10.9.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `-R` (aka `--reveal`) option to select a single file:

```
open -R "/Volumes/Server/Resources/stock1/image.eps"
```

Something like,

```
open -R "/Volumes/Server/Resources/stock1/"*.eps
```

will not select all `eps` files in the folder, but instead will select each one successively, so that the end result is only the *last* file is selected.

Comment: Thanks so much for such a quick and simple response! This is exactly what I was looking for. :) Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

@chepner's answer (`-R` option) is great if you want to highlight just one file. If you want to select multiple files, you may want to use Apple Script like this:

```
osascript -e 'tell application "Finder" to select files in folder "stock1" of folder "PHOTOS and IMAGES" of disk "Server" whose name ends with ".eps"'
```

Comment: Xiaobai, thank you very much for this related information. This is great to know and will probably come in very hand in the future for me. :) Thumbs up.